# Exponential Distribution problem with many items to be tested

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

I have the next exercise: The duration time X, in months, of a type of electrical resistance has the next probability density function:

[image]

Then if 10 electrical resistors are tested, what is the probability that none of them will last more than 4 months? and how many resistances would be tested so that with a probability of 0.9 there is at least one that lasts more than 4 months?
I know how to solve exponential some kind of distribution problems with a item tested but with many of them just I don't. Can anyone explain me the way how to do it?

Comment: Use binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `self-study` problems (including problems that are similar to
textbook homework problems) we expect you to show some of your work and then
ask for help on part(s) you can't finish. I will try to get you started.

Let a Success be that such a resistor lasts longer than 5 months.
The success probability is $p = P(X > 4) = 1 = P(X \le 4) = 0.1353,$
where $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate} = .5).$ The computation can be done in R where `pexp` is an [exponential CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). You should
write the formula for the CDF and verify the answer.

```
p = 1 - pexp(4, .5);  p
[1] 0.1353353
```

Now let the number $Y$ of successes in $n = 10$ trials be
distributed
Let $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(10, p).$ You want $P(Y = 0).$

I will let you evaluate that probability, and then figure out the second
part.